# Canvas and border displaying transparent even if no opacity was added

Tags: html, css, canvas, transparent

Dear fellow programmer

I ran into an issue recently. I added a border to my canvas and I changed some unrelated stuff. Anyway The canvas and the border got transparent. It may be caused by the border or by another change I made to the code.

It's probably something obvious and I can't seem to find it anyway. I read through all my code and still found nothing.

A search through the internet gave me no answer neither. So I'm here

Here is the  CSS code:

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: visible;
}

canvas {
    background: rgba(238, 238, 238);
    border: 6px solid rgba(238, 238, 238);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And the HTML5 code:

```
<canvas id="pong_singleplayer_canvas" height="640" width="960" style="opacity: 50%"></canvas></canvas>
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: There is an inline style of opacity on your canvas element.
`<canvas id="pong_singleplayer_canvas" height="640" width="960" style="opacity: 0.7;"></canvas>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post J. Langer's comment as an answere:

```html
<canvas id="pong_singleplayer_canvas" height="640" width="960" style="opacity: 0.7;"></canvas>
```